# Analytic solution of regression problem

Tags: regression, linear-regression, regression-analysis

I have a regression problem as below.
$$
A^* = \operatorname*{argmin}_A \| Y - AX \|_F^2
$$
where $Y$ and $X$ are matrices, and $A$ is a mapping matrix between these two matrices.

There are analytic solutions for the above problem, which is given as below.
$$
\tilde{A} = Y X^\dagger
$$
and
$$
\bar{A} = (Y X^\top) (X X^\top)^\dagger
$$
where $\dagger$ is pseudo-inverse.

I think they should have the same result. But, when I try to verify the accuracy of both solutions, they are different: $\varepsilon_1 \neq \varepsilon_2$ where
\begin{align}
\varepsilon_1 = \| Y - \tilde{A}X \|_F^2,
\varepsilon_2 = \| Y X^\top - \bar{A} (X X^\top)\|_F^2
\end{align}

In my naive thought, $\varepsilon_1 = \varepsilon_2$. Why is it different?

Comment: How did you find $\varepsilon_1$ and $\varepsilon_2$ and how did you conclude that they are different?